# Call Native iOS code

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

How do I call a native iOS function from a UnityScript?

For C# there are lots of examples out there using extern static, but I cannot find any for UnityScript.

If this is not implementable, how then can I call a C# function from the UnityScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

1) You would have to create a C# script having `extern static public` methods that call the native functions in iOS. Also create methods that call the `extern static public` methods.

2) Attach that script to a GameObject

3) Then you can use `this.getComponent(YourScript).SendMessage(FunctionName)`, as well as `this.getComponent(YourScript).FunctionName`.

You can check out https://github.com/RedTroops/Unity-SDK/wiki/iOS-and-Android-Platforms-for-Unity-C%23-scripting where I implemented this.